# A planet in which Natural elements , emits heat energy - Is Inhabitable?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, fantasy-races, species

On my alien planet, many natural elements (Soil, some plants, a certain type of stones...) emit a kind of heat energy.
Will this affect flora and fauna of my planet? Since the natural elements emit some kind of heat energy, is that planet became like a hot oven uninhabitable for hot-blood animals?

Comment: Being cold-blooded merely means that the creature can't regulate its body temperature. It has nothing to do with heat.

Comment: So increasing rate of black body radiation? Because right now, all matter (that is above absolute zero) emits thermal energy. Because as it stands your question can be answered: Yes. see black body radiation.

Answer (score 3):

> Will this affect other flora and fauna of my planet ?

your race evolved on that planet, and environmental conditions are an evolutionary driver. As such also all other living beings on that planet will be affected.

And since on our planet hot deserts are inhabited both by warm blooded and cold blooded beings, being warm blooded doesn't seem to be an obstacle in populating such areas. Evolution will find a way.

Answer (score 1):

On planet Earth, the source of heat is Sun. Then heat is distributed and kept by air or water. In many cities, (in summer) temperature reaches 117°F (47°C) in the afternoon for many days. People and animals live there. Some even work on roads or outside. I have seen camels walking on sand at 120°F (49°C).

Is there air and water on your alien planet, which distribute and retain heat? What are the highest and lowest temperatures on the planet?

Assuming that just like a hot city on earth (Turbat-Pakistan, Jazan-Saudi Arabia, Mitribah-Kuwait etc.), temperature on your planet varies from 120°F (49°C) to 90°F (32°C), then it will be hot but not uninhabitable.

But if the temperatures reach like on Mercury or Venus [around 800°F (427°C)], then it could be uninhabitable. There is no life or evolution on Mercury or Venus.